# Visibility of Android BLE pairing prompt

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I'm working on Android app that pairs and interacts with BLE accessory. When app initiates pairing with the accessory for the first time one of two things happen:

- Either phone shows pairing dialog with the field for PIN code
- Phone adds new notification to the statusbar with small BT icon.

User then has to swipe down and tap "Touch to pair with ..." notification that presents the prompt.

What does it depend upon? Is there a way to encourage OS to show dialog instead of the notification?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do about it. This is totally dependent on the OS (version/variant/manufacturer).